# Jaxx wallet backup phrase

Tags: myetherwallet, jaxx

Is it possible for an older version of jaxx wallet to give me a word for my backup phrase that isn't on MEW word list? They refuse to give me the list they use. Just refer me to the MEW one and then say that they use it as well. But I didn't write down pirate for no reason four times in a row. Smells fishy